# Script writes in reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if I asked this wrong or formatted it wrong, this is my first time here.
Basically, this script is a very, very, simple text editor. The problem is, when it writes to a file, I want it to write:

```
Hi, my name
is bob.
```

But, it writes:

```
is bob.
Hi, my name
```

How can I fix this?
The code is here:

```
import time
import os
userdir = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")
usrtxtdir = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop\\PythonEdit Output.txt")
def editor():
    words = input("\n")
    f = open(usrtxtdir,"a")
    f.write(words + '\n')
    nlq = input('Line saved. "/n" for new line. "/quit" to quit.\n$ ')
    if(nlq == '/quit'):
        print('Quitting. Your file was saved on your desktop.')
        time.sleep(2)
        return
    elif(nlq == '/n'):
        editor()
    else:
        print("Invalid command.\nBecause Brendan didn't expect for this to happen,\nthe program will quit in six seconds.\nSorry.")
        time.sleep(6)
        return
def lowlevelinput():
    cmd = input("\n$ ")
    if(cmd == "/edit"):
        editor()
    elif(cmd == "/citenote"):
        print("Well, also some help from internet tutorials.\nBut Brendan did all the scripting!")
        lowlevelinput()
print("Welcome to the PythonEdit Basic Text Editor!\nDeveloped completley by Brendan*!")
print("Type \"/citenote\" to read the citenote on the word Brendan.\nType \"/edit\" to begin editing.")
lowlevelinput()
```

Comment: By the way, sorry for not adding any notes on what the things do.

Comment: where do you close a file? close it after write...

Comment: Your code's tough to follow here, but I _think_ the issue is that you're recursing into your input functions which is reversing the output order that you expect as the call stack unwinds.  That's just speculation though.

Comment: "Line saved" - nope, line not necessarily saved. `write` doesn't promise to save anything. Writes have to be flushed for anything to be saved.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to have another citenote stating that the line isn't actually saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice puzzle. Why are the lines coming out in reverse? Because of **output buffering:**

When you write to a file, the system doesn't immediately commit your data to disk. This happens periodically (when the buffer is full), or when the file is closed. You never close `f`, so it is closed for you when `f` goes out of scope... which happens when the function `editor()` returns. But **`editor()` calls itself recursively!** So the first call to `editor()` is the last one to exit, and its output is the last to be committed to disk. Neat, eh?

To fix the problem, it is enough to close `f` as soon as you are done writing:

```
f = open(usrtxtdir,"a")
f.write(words + '\n')
f.close()   # don't forget the parentheses
```

Or the equivalent:

```
with open(usrtxtdir, "a") as f:
    f.write(words + '\n')
```

But it's better to fix the organization of your program:

1. Use a loop to run `editor()`, not recursive calls.
2. An editor should be writing out the file at the end of the session, not with every line input. Consider collecting the user input in a list of lines, and writing everything out in one go at the end.
3. If you do want to write as you go, you should open the file only once, write repeatedly, then close it when done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your file after writing, before you try to open it again. Otherwise your writes will not be finalized until the program is closed.

```
def editor():
    words = input("\n")
    f = open(usrtxtdir,"a")
    f.write(words + '\n')
    nlq = input('Line saved. "/n" for new line. "/quit" to quit.\n$ ')
    f.close()  # your missing line!
    if(nlq == '/quit'):
        print('Quitting. Your file was saved on your desktop.')
        time.sleep(2)
        return
    elif(nlq == '/n'):
        editor()
    else:
        print("Invalid command.\nBecause Brendan didn't expect for this to happen,\nthe program will quit in six seconds.\nSorry.")
        time.sleep(6)
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace:

```
f = open(usrtxtdir,"a")
f.write(words + '\n')
```

with:

```
with open(usrtxtdir,"a") as f:
    f.write(words + '\n')
```

It comes out in order.  Pretty much always use `with open()` for file access.  It handles the closing of the files for you automatically, even in the event of a crash.  Although you might consider taking text in memory and writing it only upon quit.  But that's not really part of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`file.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) documentation states: "Due to buffering, the string may not actually show up in the file until the [`flush()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) or [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) method is called"

Since you're recursively reopening the file and writing to it before closing it (or flushing the buffer), the outer value ('Hi, my name') isn't yet written when the inner frame (where you write 'is bob.') completes, which appears to automatically flush the write buffer.

You should be able to add file.flush() to correct it like this:

```
import time
import os
userdir = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")
usrtxtdir = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop\\PythonEdit Output.txt")
def editor():
    words = input("\n")
    f = open(usrtxtdir,"a")
    f.write(words + '\n')
    f.flush() # <-----   ADD THIS LINE HERE   -----< #
    nlq = input('Line saved. "/n" for new line. "/quit" to quit.\n$ ')
    if(nlq == '/quit'):
        print('Quitting. Your file was saved on your desktop.')
        time.sleep(2)
        return
    elif(nlq == '/n'):
        editor()
    else:
        print("Invalid command.\nBecause Brendan didn't expect for this to happen,\nthe program will quit in six seconds.\nSorry.")
        time.sleep(6)
        return
def lowlevelinput():
    cmd = input("\n$ ")
    if(cmd == "/edit"):
        editor()
    elif(cmd == "/citenote"):
        print("Well, also some help from internet tutorials.\nBut Brendan did all the scripting!")
        lowlevelinput()
print("Welcome to the PythonEdit Basic Text Editor!\nDeveloped completley by Brendan*!")
print("Type \"/citenote\" to read the citenote on the word Brendan.\nType \"/edit\" to begin editing.")
lowlevelinput()
```

Also, don't forget to close your file after you're done with it!